# HP 15s eq0355ng keyboad issue on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-22.04

I have a HP 15s eq0355ng and I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. The problem is, that the keyboard layout is different from a usual QWERTZ keyobard.

The key for the symbols greater, smaller and pipe is next to the left Arrow-key instead of normally right next to the Shift-key. Ubuntu is not recognizing this layout correctly, so therefore the button for this keys is shown as dead-button and is not working at all.

Is there any solution for this? Can someone help here out please?

Thanks in advance.

I tried to reconfigure the keyboard-configuration with the command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` but I could not find any keyboard layout there, what is the same as for my laptop or I just don't know, which one to choose. But there is not much HP related keyboard models available and from all of what is there, none is fitting to my laptop keyboard layout.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on the same problem for a long time.
Something i found was a [Input Remapper](https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper) by someone called [Tobi](https://github.com/sezanzeb). Using this Software i was able to remap my <kbd>Control Right</kbd> Key to the <kbd>>, < and |</kbd> key. To do so you need to install some programs needed for the input remapper.

```
sudo apt install python3-setuptools gettext
```

Now you can download the `.deb` file from GitHub and install the Software or use the following commands.

```
wget https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper/releases/download/2.0.0/input-remapper-2.0.0.deb
sudo dpkg -i input-remapper-2.0.0.deb
```

Remember to check for a newer version and update the version in the both commands.

Now you just have to:

1. Start the Application
2. Select your Keyboard
3. Open or Create a Preset
4. Add a Input by clicking the `Add` Button in the bottom left Corner
5. Hit Record and then press the key you want to Remap
6. Then On the right side select `Key or Macro` as Type and `Keyboard` as Target and put `less` in the input field
7. Click Apply on the Top and you should all be set

Something else i found was [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions?action=show&redirect=Howto%3A+Custom+keyboard+layout+definitions) Website, which explains how to create a custom Keyboard Layout. But i am currently not able to give you instructions for that, since im just checking it out.